# C# setting that works similar to VS C++ /ASSEMBLYLINKRESOURCE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, shared-libraries, unmanaged

I have the follwoing scenario:

- C# project A uses an unmanaged dll via p/invoke: `[DllImport("someUnmanaged.dll")]`
- project A is configured to copy "someUnmanaged.dll" to the project bin folder when compiling. This works fine.
- C# project B, C and D all reference A. But they do not automatically copy the unmanaged dll. I have to configure each of those projects to copy the unmanaged dll.
- So, If another developer wants to use my projectA.dll, they have to know exactly which unmanged dlls to copy, and how to configure their VS project.

If project A is a managed c++/cli project instead of a c# project, I can use `/ASSEMBLYLINKRESOURCE "...\someUnmanaged.dll"` to tell the compiler to always copy someUnmanaged.dll whenever it copies projectA.dll.

*(this is a setting in Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Assembly Link Resource)*

`/ASSEMBLYLINKRESOURCE` somehow annotates `projectA.dll`, so that when this dll is referenced in another project, visual studio will automatically search for `someUnmanaged.dll` as well, and copy both during compilation.

How can I get this functionality in a c# project?

Comment: Hmm not sure if this is exactly what you want but maybe take a look to the DllImport attribute?

Comment: I'll try to clarify: using `[DllImport("someUnmanaged.dll")]` in c# code, I can call functions from unmanaged dlls. But if the unmanaged dll is missing, it will crash. I can configure VS to copy the unmanaged dll to the project ouput folder. But if I use `DllImport` in one VS project, and then reference that VS project in another VS project, it will not automatically copy the unmanaged dll to the second project; so I have to configure a copy action in each new project. With /ASSEMBLYLINKRESOURCE, I can tell the compiler "these two DLL belong together, always copy both"